# Customize TabbedPage color schema - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

Is there a way I can customize the color schema of tabs on `Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage` object so it does not take the default look and feel of the target platform?

I would like to change font color, background and current selected tab color.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to use a custom renderer.

Here is an example for iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(TabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
            TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Black;
            TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        }
    }
}
```

Just past this class in the Xamarin.iOS project.

For Xamarin.Android you could also use a custom renderer to accomplish the same. The Android implementation of the custom renderer looks different from the iOS version.

Comment: How can I do it for Android?

Answer (score 4):

Late for the party.

Now you can change the tabbed page background color as follows

**BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;**

Below links may help you more

[How to change color of tabbed page indicator in Xamarin.Droid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256975/how-to-change-color-of-tabbed-page-indicator-in-xamarin-droid)

http://thatcsharpguy.com/post/platformtabbedpage-xamarin-forms-en/

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way in `Xamarin.Forms`, but that's really easy to do in your platform-specific projects. e.g. by using UIAppearance on `iOS`.

Answer (score 1):

In tabbed page , in order to change the header color in xamarin forms not in android native.

Tabbed page code:

```
 class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {
        LoginManager app;

        public MainPage(LoginManager ilm)
        {

            app = ilm;
            Title = "Infrastructure";
            Icon = "server.png";            


            this.BarTextColor = Color.White;
            this.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Blue;


            Children.Add(new AssetsView());
            Children.Add(new ServiceView());

            ToolbarItem tbi = new ToolbarItem() {
                Text = "Logout",
                Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary,
                Priority = 0,       



            };
```

AssetView Code:

```
 public AssetView()
        {
            Title = "Assets";           



           this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("D3D3D3");

            list = new AssetsList();

            searchbar = new SearchBar()
            {

                Placeholder = "Search",
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                CancelButtonColor = Color.Black,
                PlaceholderColor = Color.Black


            };
```

ServiceView Code:

```
  public class ServiceView : ContentPage
    {

        ServiceList list;
        SearchBar searchbar;


        public ServiceView()
        {
            Title = "Services";
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("D3D3D3");

            list = new ServiceList();

            searchbar = new SearchBar()
            {
                Placeholder = "Search",
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                CancelButtonColor = Color.Black,
                PlaceholderColor = Color.Black
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this in Android by doing the following:

Cast your Current.MainPage to a TabbedPage - this will let you set the properties.

```
((TabbedPage)Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(settings.AppSecondaryColour);
```

[image]

You Should be able to change the other properties you wish in the same way.  I have NOT tested this in IOS yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way :

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:SilCoyLuhn.Views"
            x:Class="SilCoyLuhn.Views.MainPage"
            BarBackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
            BarTextColor="{StaticResource LightTextColor}">

    <TabbedPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Primary">#9DD69F</Color>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#E1F4E0</Color>
            <Color x:Key="LightTextColor">#999999</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        </TabbedPage.Resources>
</TabbedPage>
```

In the `<TabbedPage.Resources>`, I define static ressources used as `BarBackgroundColor` and `BarTextColor`.