# How to change color of tabbed page indicator in Xamarin.Droid?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, indicator, tabbedpage

I'm building an application with **Xamarin.Forms** and a Portable Class Library. I have a tabbed page. I want to change the color of the tabbed page indicator. Changing the rest of the layout is something I already managed, the only thing I do need is to change the light blue tabbed page indicator like shown below: 
[image]

I couldn't find anything that could work in Xamarin.Droid. This is the code that creates the tabbed page with content:

```
class TabbedPageTry : TabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPageTry()
    { 
        Title = "TabbedPage";

        var myPages = new CategoryDAO().GetCategories();
        foreach (var item in myPages)
        {
            Children.Add(new TabPage(item.CategoryID) { BindingContext = item });
        }
    }

    public class TabPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TabPage(int categoryID)
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 0, 0);

            var listView = new ListView
            {

                SeparatorColor = Color.FromHex("#101010"),
                ItemsSource = new CourseDAO().GetCourses(),
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled = false,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            };

            this.SetBinding(Page.TitleProperty, "Name");
            Content = listView;
        }
}
```

Because the application is being made Visual Studio with Xamarin.Forms my question is not answered yet. All the question I found are for Android specific, this is **NOT** what I am looking for. What I need is the C# solution to my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TabLayout color of selected tab underline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725109/tablayout-color-of-selected-tab-underline)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are [using AppCompat](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/android/appcompat/) in your Android platform project, in your TabLayout axml file use the tabIndicatorColor property to do this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
   ....
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#123456" />
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it by `12 minutes

Comment: This is the right solution, when the AppCompat (Material Design) in your Android project does work. Which is not the case in my project, but this is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `FormsAppCompatActivity` (Material Design), then all you have to do is open the `Tabbar.axml` file in the droid project's Resources folder and change the color set for `app:tabIndicatorColor`. For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF3300" <!-- Set indicator color here, sets it to red-->
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `mainview.xaml.cs`, inside public `MainView()`:

```
On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarSelectedItemColor(enter color here)

On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarItemColor(enter color here)
```

Comment: SetBarSelectedItemColor doesn't change anything for me : /. No forms actions affect the tab colors. The only way I've gotten the color to change is ActionBar.SetStackedBackgroundDrawable(new Android.Graphics.Drawables.ColorDrawable(color.ToAndroid())). This must be run from the android-specific project.

Comment: We worked out why SetBarSelectedItemColor wasn't working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717492/xamarin-forms-platform-specific-setbarselecteditemcolor-has-no-effect/54758200?noredirect=1#comment96488789_54758200). It sets the text color for the active tab, not the tabIndicatorColor

Comment: This is obsolete