# Change color tabindicatorcolor xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to change the tabindicatorcolor in **MainPage.xaml**   but I cannot see the properties tabindicatorcolor. They mention here using [AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256975/how-to-change-color-of-tabbed-page-indicator-in-xamarin-droid), I already imported the Android Support Library v7 AppCompat from NuGet and mentioned to check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40314315/17786013) **Resources/layout/Tabbar.axml** but I cannot see in my MyProject.Android project.

What else did I missed? Sorry, just new with programming.
Edit: I'm using Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a layout folder inside you Resources folder of Android platform of Xamarin.Forms project.

Then create `tabbar.xml` in the layout folder. Add the code below for the file. I set indicator color to red for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF3300"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

And do not forget to set the `TabLayoutResource` in MainActivity.

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TabLayoutResource= Resource.Layout.tabbar;

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

For now, when you use the tabbedpage in Xamarin.Forms, you would have a red tabindicatorcolor.

Comment: Hey, is there any directory to see all the resource for android? For example that tabbar.xml, as I see there's a bunch of codes. Btw, your solution works. Thanks.

Comment: Xamarin.Android: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/  Xamarin.Android is only a layer of wrapper for Android native libraries. For more details, we need to check the native Android Developer. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout